# Android keyboard inside a keyboard

Tags: android, search, keyboard, box

I am new in developing for Android, and I want to make a keyboard of my own, and I want it to have a search box inside it.
Is it possible that the search box will use a different keyboard then mine (exclude mine from the keyboards options)?
Thanks!!

Edit
I would like something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nec3l.png) and when someone will press the text box, one of his other installed keyboards will be used.

Comment: Attach a image of keyboard you wanted to design

Comment: Hey, i've edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Make a Custom EditText Class like this

```
 public class GifEditText extends EditText {
        public GifEditText(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public GifEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public GifEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

        @Override
        public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo editorInfo) {
            final InputConnection ic = super.onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo);
            EditorInfoCompat.setContentMimeTypes(editorInfo,
                    new String[]{"image/gif"});

            final InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener callback =
                    new InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onCommitContent(InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfo,
                                                       int flags, Bundle opts) {
                            // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously
                            if (BuildCompat.isAtLeastNMR1() && (flags &
                                    InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) != 0) {
                                try {
                                    inputContentInfo.requestPermission();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    return false; // return false if failed
                                }
                            }

                            // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously.
                            // call inputContentInfo.releasePermission() as needed.

                            return true;  // return true if succeeded
                        }
                    };
            return InputConnectionCompat.createWrapper(ic, editorInfo, callback);
        }
    }
```

And use like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.test.GifEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Test gif" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Which part of the code indicates that my keyboard wont be the one that opens when the user enters the EditText?